# C# MVC Adding a record to a table with form and parameters

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am having an issue with my add to a database record.
What I am attempting to do is add a record with parameters sent from a form. I am grabbing an item from a table giving a quantity and them adding it to an orders table.

I am adding it to the OrderDetails table so I need the orderId. Which I grab from the Url.
Below is my code, It is not working. It could probably be simplified but I am not sure where to modify this.

Form on Page:

```
   @{ var OrderId = Request.Url.Segments[3];}
        <td>
            <form method="GET" action="~/OrderManager/AddToOrder/@OrderId" _lpchecked="1">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Qty</span>
                        </div>
                        <input style="max-width:75px;" aria-label="Qty" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" min="1" name="quantity">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="submit" onchange="usercheck">Add To Order</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
```

Here is my Controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            GeneralEntities db = new GeneralEntities();
            var result = db.Extras.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
            return View(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult AddToOrder(int OrderId, string id, int quantity)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            GeneralEntities ExtrasDb = new GeneralEntities(); 
            
            var addedExtra = ExtrasDb.Extras
                .Single(ext => ext.ExtrasName == id);

            var extra = new OrderDetail 
            {
                OrderId = OrderId,
                Extras = addedExtra.BillingExtrasId,                 
                Quantity = quantity,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            ExtrasDb.OrderDetails.Add(extra);

            sb.Append("Sumitted");
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }

        return Content(sb.ToString());

    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Revised Code Update:

I changed some things. I seem to have what i need now and it says it submits but it does not save it to the table..

Revised form:

```
@{ var OrderId = Request.Url.Segments[3];}
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="~/OrdersManager/Add/" _lpchecked="1">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Qty</span>
                        </div>
                        <input data-val="true" id="OrderId" name="OrderId" type="hidden" value="@OrderId" />
                        <input data-val="true" id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="@item.BillingExtrasId" />
                        <input style="max-width:75px;" aria-label="Qty" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" min="1" name="quantity">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="submit" onchange="usercheck">Add To Order</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
```

Revised Controller Code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(int OrderId, Guid id, int quantity)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            GeneralEntities ExtrasDb = new GeneralEntities(); 
            // Retrieve the album from the database
            var addedExtra = ExtrasDb.Extras
                .Single(ext => ext.BillingExtrasId == id);

            var extra = new OrderDetail 
            {
                OrderId = OrderId,
                Extras = addedExtra.BillingExtrasId,
                UnitPrice = addedExtra.Price,
                Quantity = quantity,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            ExtrasDb.OrderDetails.Add(extra);

            sb.Append("Sumitted");
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }

        return Content(sb.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Please add more details to question like what is the exact issue you are facing. Here what is the value for quantity and id when `AddToOrder` is called?.

Comment: I think i know the latest issue. I forgot to add Save to  the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
ExtrasDb.SaveChanges();
```

right before the first `return` statement inside of the `try` block.

(You found the mistake and mentioned it in your comment. I'm just confirming and turning it into an answer.)